# How to set keyboard indicator light from windows kernel mode driver?

Tags: c, kernel, driver

I want to write a kernel mode program that toggles the numlock light on the keyboard when a key is pressed.

I started by modifying the **kbfiltr.c** provided with the `WinDDK` samples, using the `KbFilter_ServiceCallback routine` to intercept a key and I'm trying to send an `(IOCTL_KEYBOARD_SET_INDICATORS)` by **IRP** to set the light.

I'm quite new to driver development and I can't find how to code this properly.

Can anyone help out by giving direction to any code examples?

Comment: Sample code quickly turns up if you look IOCTL_KEYBOARD_SET_INDICATORS up on google.

Comment: I didn't discover any that I found helpful, specifically relating to kernel mode kb filter.

Comment: Did you see [this one](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/32092-toggle-led-lights/)?

Comment: Thanks, I might come back to that one later, but right now I wonder if someone can help me fill in the parameters for IoBuildDeviceIoControlRequest() to set keyboard indicator lights. I'm particularly unsure what DeviceObject will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with information and source code provided by Microsoft at:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326315